# Stop running processes after a Promise is rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using the following code which working OK, but the problem is that when I get an error, I want it to stops all the other promises. For example if `chi.getCommand(val1, val2)`, will send a reject and I got to the exception catch, I want to cancel the promises for `chss.exe` and `app.getStatus(12);` How can I achieve that?

```
  var start = Promise.all([
      chi.getCommand(val1, val2),
      chi.findAndUpdateCustomer()
    ]).spread(function (command, customer) {
        return chss.exe(runnableDoc, command, customer)
                 .delay(10)
                 .then(function (val) {
                   if (val) console.log(val);
                   return app.getStatus(12);
                 });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        // catch and handle errors and when it come to here I want it to stops all the chain above
    });
```

This is the code of get command in short:

```
function getCommand(method, cmd) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    ...
    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: here!' + data);
        reject(data);
    });
}
```

The console log **stderr: here!** are printed so the resolve are called!

**UPDATE1**

The only thing which stops the getStatus is when I put the `process.exit(1)` But this kill all the process, I just want to stop all the chain of the function getCommand in case Im **arriving to the catch block**,

> 1. is there a way?
> 2. is it bug in blueBird ? I use "bluebird": "2.9.34"

function getCommand(method, cmd) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var ls = spawn("cmdbug",["/c","npm install express --save"]);


    ls.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
    });
```

the error which I got is

> { [Error: spawn cmdr ENOENT]
>     code: 'ENOENT',
>     errno: 'ENOENT',
>     syscall: 'spawn cmdbug',
>     path: 'cmdr',
>     spawnargs: [ '/g', 'npm install express --save' ] }
>   { [Error: spawn cmdbug ENOENT]
>     code: 'ENOENT',
>     errno: 'ENOENT',
>     syscall: 'spawn cmdbug',
>     path: 'cmdr',
>     spawnargs: [ '/g', 'npm install express --save' ] }
>   Child process failed with code  -4058

And still the process of getStatus is writing to the console.

The code which I use and not for testing is:

The **getCommand** is the function that throw the **error!**

```
var start= function () {
    return new Promise.all([
        childP.getChildProcessCommand(val1, val2),
        childP.findAndUpdateCustomer()
    ]).spread(function (cmd, updated) {
            //Execute child process
            return Promise.all([
                childP.getCommand('spawn', cmd),
                app.getStatus(51000,10,1);
            ]).catch(function (err) {
                // catch and handle errors
                console.log("An error occur: " + err);
                return;
            })
        }).catch(function (err) {
            // catch and handle errors
            console.log("An error occur: " + err);
            return;
        })
}();
```

**The code for check status is:**

```
// Returns a promise that resolves when the port is open

checkPortStatus: function(port, host){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    portscanner.checkPortStatus(port, host, function(error, status) {
      if(error)
        reject(error);
      else if(status === 'open')
        resolve(status);
      else
        reject(new Error('Port is not open'));
    });
  });
},

// THE API function
getStatus: function(port, retriesLeft) {

  const TIME_BETWEEN_CHECKS = 1000;
  const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
  const RETRIES = 20;
  retriesLeft = retriesLeft === void 0 ? RETRIES : retriesLeft;

  if(!port) throw new Error('Port is required');
  if(retriesLeft === 0) Promise.reject('Timed Out');

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // If it rejects, we do added work.
    this.checkPortStatus(port, host).then(resolve, error => {
     console.log("Waiting for port " + port + " attempt: " + retry);
      setTimeout(() => {

        this.getStatus(port, retriesLeft - 1).then(resolve, reject);

      }, TIME_BETWEEN_CHECKS);
    });
  });
}
```

> And I see the error in the console and still see the console log of
>   the following for 10 attempts. console.log("Waiting for port " + port
>   + " attempt: " + retry);

**UPDATE2**
When trying to change As @artur suggest in the second option I got error in the recoursive call the error is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

This is what I've tried:

```
getStatus: function(port, retriesLeft) {

  const TIME_BETWEEN_CHECKS = 1000;
  const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
  const RETRIES = 20;
  retriesLeft = retriesLeft === void 0 ? RETRIES : retriesLeft;

  if(!port) throw new Error('Port is required');
  if(retriesLeft === 0) Promise.reject('Timed Out');

  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // If it rejects, we do added work.
    this.checkPortStatus(port, host).then(resolve, error => {
     console.log("Waiting for port " + port + " attempt: " + retry);
      setTimeout(() => {
        //The error in the following recursive call
        this.getStatus(port, retriesLeft - 1).then(resolve, reject);

      }, TIME_BETWEEN_CHECKS);
      }).catch(function (error) {
         return reject(error);
     });
        return {
            promise:promise,
    cancel: function() {
        console.log('cancelling');
        clearTimeout(token);
        }

       }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: `Promise.all` does that already. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*will stops*". If a promise is rejected, `spread` and `then` callbacks are not executed at all.

Comment: @gnerkus - not in this case I got error from getCommand and chss.exe is still running...I want it to stops

Comment: @Bergi - in my case what happen is that getCommand return an error (reject) and this will stops in the catch but the app.getStatus(12); is still running...

Comment: @Mark: I'm pretty sure it isn't. Maybe it was called from somewhere else?

Comment: If `app.getStatus(12)` *and* the `catch` callback are executed, this only can mean that `getCommand` did not reject its promise but `getStatus` did.

Comment: @Bergi - please see my update of the code

Comment: @Bergi - so in this case I saw the console.log so the promise is rejected (line after),and I see that the getStatus still working, what you suggest to do to overcome this?

Comment: Are you sure you are not fulfilling/resolving before rejecting the promise?

Comment: @Tiago - yes Im sure  :)

Comment: @Bergi - Do you have and hint how can I avoid this ? some workaround?

Comment: I'm still pretty sure there's a mistake in the code you haven't shown to us (a bug in Bluebird is unlikely). Can you break your code down to a example that you can post here in complete and that consistently reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: @bergi which method do you want my to post the code? there is some methods that you think that can provide the problem?

Comment: @Mark: All the methods that you are using in the snippet… or stub them with something simple as long as the erroneous behaviour prevails. Also it would be nice if your example did not depend on some child process event emitter but some very simple async primitive (`setTimeout` or so).

Comment: @Bergi - Well, but I think that the problem is coming from the child process since I spawn process(in the getCommand) and the event emitter catch the error print to the console and reject...the tree dots in the question is the spawn of the process.

Comment: @Mark: Please log all of the events you're listening to, and show us that log then. Also make sure to know what really happens with the promise that `chi.getCommand(val1, val2)` returns, by installing a `.then(console.log.bind(console,"fulfilled"), console.error.bind(console,"rejected"))` listener on it (put the promise in a variable and use it multiple times).

Comment: Btw, do you get the same `err` in the catch handler as the `data` on the `stderr` listener?

Comment: @Bergi - can you please elborate on installing .then(console.log.bind(console,"fulfilled") where and how ?can you provide example/reference?

Comment: Use `var p = chi.getCommand(val1, val2); p.then(console.log.bind(console,"fulfilled"), console.error.bind(console,"rejected")); var start = Promise.all([p, chi.findAndUpdateCustomer()])…`. With that we should be able to distinguish your problems with the child process from problems with `all`/`spread`/`getStatus`/`catch` (if there are any).

Comment: @Bergi - Thanks you very much currently my linux system is down as soon it will be up again i'll try your suggestion

Comment: Is there an iteration? Is `app.getStatus(12)` occurring in one iteration, and the catch in another iteration?

Comment: @Bergi - as you asked I've added all the code ,since my system is down I did test that reproduce the error exactly buy changing cmd to cmdbug,this is the full code please see the code after update1,Thank you!

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - please see the full code after update1

Comment: OK, my comment is academic now that @Bergi has answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Esailija pointed out `bluebird` has cancellation mechanism built-in - which is really nice and for sure **totally fine** for simple async computations.

```js
Promise.config({
  cancellation: true
});

function createCancellableMock(result, time) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject, onCancel) {

    // var child = runCommand();
    var token = setTimeout(function() {
      if (result) {
        console.log('almost done', result);
        resolve(result);
      } else {
        reject('_ERR_');
      }
    }, time);

    onCancel(function() {
      console.log('cancelling');
      // child.kill('SIGTERM');
      clearTimeout(token);
    })
  })

}

var op1 = createCancellableMock('ok-1', 1000);
//var op2 = createCancellableMock('ok-2', 500);
var op2 = createCancellableMock(null, 500); // will be rejected

Promise.all([op1, op2])
  .spread(function(v1, v2) {
    console.log('BOTH-OK', v1, v2)
  })
  .catch(function() {
    console.error('ERROR');
    op1.cancel();
  })
  .finally(function() {
    console.log('finally');
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.0/bluebird.core.js"></script>
```

#### UPDATE

You can cancel recursively defined actions (such as retries). The best strategy in such a case is not to mangle the action itself with the recursive behavior. In the below snippet I created a very simple wrapper which illustrates my point.

```js
var TOO_MANY_RETRIES_ERROR = 'too_many_retries_error';
var PROB_OF_FAIL = 0.8;
var INTERVAL = 200;
var RETRIES = 5;

var CANCEL_AFTER = null;
//var CANCEL_AFTER = INTERVAL * (RETRIES/2);

Promise.config({
  cancellation: true
});

function retryWithCancel(params) {

  // params = {op - operation to retry (it should return a promise, which either ),
  // interval - between retries, retries - number of retries }

  console.log('running, retries left ', params.retries);

  params = Object.assign({}, params); // copy params - no side-effects please
  params.retries--;
  if (params.retries <= 0) {
    console.error('too many retries');
    return Promise.reject(new Error(TOO_MANY_RETRIES_ERROR));
  }

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject, onCancel) {

    var o = params.op()
      .catch(function() {
        return Promise.delay(params.interval)
          .then(retryWithCancel.bind(null, params))
          .catch(reject)
      })
      .then(resolve)


    onCancel(function() {
      console.log('Cancelling, retries left: ', params.retries);
      o.cancel();
    });

  })

}

function fakeOperation() {

  return Promise.delay(100)
    .then(function() {
      if (Math.random() > PROB_OF_FAIL) {
        return Promise.resolve('SUCCESS');
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(new Error('ERROR'));
      }

    })
}

var p = retryWithCancel({
    op: fakeOperation,
    interval: INTERVAL,
    retries: RETRIES
  })
  .then(console.log.bind(console))
  .catch(console.error.bind(console))
  .finally(console.log.bind(console, 'done'))

if (CANCEL_AFTER) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    p.cancel();
  }, CANCEL_AFTER)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.1/bluebird.js"></script>
```

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

In general promises are great but they do not offer cancellation mechanism out of the box. It is pretty problematic in some scenarios (e.g. https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/27) and in your case option to cancel would be pretty handy as well. The only valid option is to add it yourself.

### basic promise based solution

I distilled the problem to bare minimum and made it browser runnable.
The downside of the below approach is that after cancellation the promise will never `resolve` nor `reject` - which in general case is surely [unacceptable](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md#promise-uncancelable). Alternatively `.cancel` may reject the promise with some special symbol. Neither of these approaches seem elegant.

```js
function createCancellableMock(result, time) {
    
    // child = null;
    var token = null ;
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        
        // child = runCommand();
        token = setTimeout(function() {
            if (result) {
                console.log('almost done', result);
                resolve(result);
            } 
            else {
                reject('_ERR_');
            }
        }, time);
    }
    )
    
    return {
        promise: p,
        cancel: function() {
            console.log('cancelling');
            // child.kill('SIGTERM');
            clearTimeout(token);
        }
    }
}

var op1 = createCancellableMock('ok-1', 1000);
// var op2 = createCancellableMock('ok-2', 500);
var op2 = createCancellableMock(null, 500); // will be rejected

Promise.all([op1.promise, op2.promise])
.then(function(vs) { // no spread in native implemantation
    console.log('BOTH-OK', vs[0], vs[1])
})
.catch(function() {
    console.error('ERROR');
    op1.cancel();
})
```

### observable based solution

For basic sequence of operations promises are fine, but there is a way more superior approach available: namely observables. Not only they offer built-in cancellation / disposing mechanism, but allow to deal with multiple values emitted and keep sophisticated async execution under very strict control.

```js
  function createCancellableMock(result, time) {

    return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {

      var done = false;
      var token = setTimeout(function() {
        if (result) {
          console.log('almost done: ' + result);
          observer.onNext(result);
          observer.onCompleted();
        } else {
          observer.onError('_ERR_');
        }
      }, time);

      // this will be called upon `disposed`
      return function() {
        console.log('disposing, done: ', done);
        if (!done) {
          clearTimeout(token);
        }
      }

    })

  }

  var op1 = createCancellableMock('ok-1', 1000);
  //var op2 = createCancellableMock('ok-2', 500);
  var op2 = createCancellableMock(null, 500); // will be rejected

  op1.zip(op2)
    .catch(function(err) {
      // it was disposed automatically :) hurray
      console.log('Caught', err);
      // return Rx.Observable.empty(); // swallowing
      return Rx.Observable.throw(err); // throwing

    })
    .subscribe(function(vs) {
        console.log('BOTH-OK', vs[0], vs[1])
      },
      function(err) {
        console.error('Unhandled error', err);
      },
      function() {
        console.log('Upon successful termination.')
      }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.7/rx.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bluebird has cancellation out of the box

Comment: @Esailija Oh cool - did not know. So even easier - will update my answer. Btw. thanks for this really cool project.

Comment: The book's author is wrong and has been shown wrong in any arguments he has had yet he still continues to write that crap :/

Comment: @Esailija for me approach you created in the `bluebird` lib makes perfect sense. Right now - due to lack of native cancellation mechanism - we are in a situation where we cannot abort 'fetch' requests, which on its own is totally insane.

Comment: The spec for cancelable promises is worked on https://github.com/domenic/cancelable-promise

Comment: @arturgrzesiak - Thanks a lot for elaborating answer 1+( i learned something new :) , when I use the Promise.config I got error TypeError: Promise.config is not a function , how can I overcome this? I use version 2.94

Comment: Sorry I mean version 2.9.34,another question in the original question you put the chancel in the return ,but how should I adopt the code of getStatus to work like this ( you can see this code in the end of the post)

Comment: @Esailija - I'm currently working on version 2.9.34(not having the option to upgrade soon "company things- legals etc" :( is there a way to use the cancellation in 2.9.34 version ? I ask it since I saw it redesigned... http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html, btw We are using bluebird in our company after using Q and it's so better by performance/ features /maintenance

Comment: @Mark 2.x has cancellation too (although very different from 3.x), you can read the docs from https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/2.x/API.md

Comment: @Mark Updated my answer to include `retry` scenario.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak - Thanks :) but sorry I didnt quit understand what you did,can you please provide example with the context of appStatus(didnt find when you use the port scanner etc) and the start function? btw it will be great if you can do it with bluebird 2.9.34

Comment: @Mark `retryWithCancel` is a generic mechanism of retrying any function that returns a cancellable promise. `fakeOperation` is just a function that returns resolved/rejected promise with some probabilities. In your case, you should pass: `function action(){return getStatus(port)}` as `params.op` to `retryWithCancel`. I cannot find 2.9.34 docs online, but Esailija said that there is a cancellation mechanism built-in as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your actual code (the one from UPDATE1) you are running `getCommand` concurrently to `getStatus`, not in sequence. You're calling (starting) both of them *before* the child process fails, and when it does there is nothing that would stop `getStatus`.

Just chain them together like in your first snippet, where a rejection in `getCommand` will cause `getStatus` to not run at all. You can use

```
childP.getCommand('spawn', cmd)
.timeout(5000)
.then(function(cmdresult) {
    return app.getStatus(51000, 10, 1);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("An error occured: " + err);
});
```

Comment: Well this is a big problem :-( it seems that the child process is sometimes doesn't emit any events (this command in the post is just an example in real time I m invoking application ) so it cant be resolved in this case and I cannot start the app.getStatus,this is the reason that I put them in parallel ...if this is the case what would you suggest?

Comment: A timeout, probably? But I'm not sure I understood what your code is supposed to do. I mean, the results of `getStatus` are never used anywhere, so why do you call it at all?

Comment: The scenario is like this: I spawn app and then examine the port to get the status when it  open, when it open I raise some events(didnt provide it in the post since I want to make it short...)  and then proceed with other process...,what do you mean by timeout can you please provide example?

Comment: Well you say that your child process sometimes doesn't emit any events. What do you want to do in that case, hang infinitely? Or fail after some timeout occurs?

Comment: What are you suggesting to do in this case ,Im opened to ideas...,the child process which doesnt emit any events this is given 
unfortunately :(

Comment: if it emit any event I can do reject/resolve and then put it on promise chain and use then...but this is not the case here

Comment: You can just put a [`.timeout()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/timeout.html) on it.

Comment: ok 1+ ,Can you please add the example for update1 with the timeout and I close this post if you think that this is my best thing to proceed,Thanks sir!

Comment: when I use it like your proposal  I got error An error occured: TimeoutError: operation timed out even when I change the timeout to 1000, any idea why?

Comment: How long is `cmdbug` usually taking? 5000 means 5 seconds.

Comment: Not sure it deadpans on the system can be from 1 to 15 seconds...,maybe there is other approch for example if I got error emit it from the catch and then stops the getStatus,what do you think? but not sure how to do it..I mean to keep the code as it was before (update1) without the timetout

Comment: You could pass the `getCommand()` promise into the `getStatus()` as a paramter, and stop the recursion when it [is rejected](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/isrejected.html)

Comment: Can you please give example in your answer? do you think this is a better approach the raising an event from the catch?

Comment: can you please assist?